# Django hide date field from form

Tags: python, django, forms

I wish to hide a date field from the user, but process it as part of a form so that I know what date the form was sent. I also wish to display this date under the Django admin.

**models.py**

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
   payment_type = models.ForeignKey('CardChoices', related_name='Payment Types')
   card_name = models.CharField(max_length=26, default=None, validators=[alphanumeric_RE]) 
   card_number = models.CharField(max_length=19, default=None)
   security_code = models.IntegerField(max_length=3, default=None) 
   expiry_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
   date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.card_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = [ "date" ]
```

**forms.py**

```
class PurchaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget, initial=date.today)

    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = "__all__"
```

I've tried hiding the field under Meta using the exclude tag, and only adding the fields that I need under fields, but it still displays all of them. I've tried using `forms.HiddenInput()` which does hide the input, but it also hides the value  from the admin. Though I found this which shows the date, but seems to repeat it twice:

```
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None): #duplicating entries
        if obj:
             return ["date"]
        return self.readonly_fields
```

And with `HiddenInput` set, the form hides the field but still asks for a valid date to be entered.

If my understanding is correct, I can't use `auto_now_add` on a form either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove date from PurchaseFrom. Rather than fields = ('__ all__'), it is better to write all your fields one by one. Later on if your model change, you may want to control what the form displays..  Anyway, it shouldn't appear if it is not in the list of "fields" in the Meta. You could add the auto_now in the models.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I will take note of that. Quite avoiding the obvious there...

Comment: You do not need to have a `default=` as you already have `auto_now` set to true. Also you may want to think about whether `auto_now_add` is not more appropriate for what you are doing as `auto_now` will update the date every time the object is modified. The docs contains all about fields and datetimes

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.11

```
import datetime
from django import forms

class PurchaseForm(forms.Form):
    date = forms.DateTimeField(initial=datetime.datetime.now, 
        widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```